# What's the "-Ydebug-error" option in scala 2? it should print every stack traces of each compilation error

Tags: scala, scala-compiler, scala-2.13

When I'm debugging a complex scala plugin, I sometimes encounter unknown errors, I want the compiler to print out the stacktrace that triggers each error, to make sure that those errors are not caused by my pluin.

In scala 3 this option can be enabled by "-Ydebug-error", but I can't find its counterpart in the latest scala 2.13.7.

How can I enable this option?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the compiler options and the available verbose settings on the Scala 2 documentation page here : https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html#Verbose_Settings

Comment: I have found "-Yissue-debug" and it doesn't do the same, the description looks similar tho

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunatly, I don't think there is one that would do the same thing. It was added in Scala 3 :

Documentation here : https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/options-new.html

In Scala 2, the closest option would be `-Vissue` or `-Yissue-debug`

Comment: They are gone. I've searched the Scala 2.13 source code and found that those definition are not used anywhere. I'm working on a patch to add it back